Consumption Flex Timer Functions Error with Prisma (Typescript)
Tried to migrate from regular consumption plan to Consumption Flex. Works fine locally however causes the function app to error with "Error retrieving host status" the moment a function utilizing prisma is deployed. Trying to view the function Filesystem logs displays "Unable to fetch the host status of your function app. To use log streaming, please make sure your function host is running." and the sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net site for logs returns a 404.
I've tried generating a new project from scratch - works with a regular HTTP function but the app dies when using a Timer trigger.
Anyone else come across this issue or know of a fix?

Check if below solution helps to fix the issue.


Re-deploy the function to a new function app.
Configure the Application Insights under Function App=>Monitoring and check the error logs.


I have created a Typescript Timer Trigger function and able to deploy the function to Azure flex consumption plan function app.
9:52:35 PM kpflexfn: Starting deployment...
9:52:43 PM kpflexfn: Creating zip package...
9:52:43 PM kpflexfn: Adding 397 files to zip package...
//logs
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: Zip package size: 2.37 MB
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: Starting deployment pipeline.
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: [ValidationStep] starting.
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: [AppSettingValidation] starting.
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: [DeploymentStorageValidation] starting.
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: Validation completed
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: [SourcePackageUriDownloadStep] starting.
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: Zip package is present at /tmp/zipdeploy/afc58a19-91a7-4eb2-8fde-5eda946c06c1.zip
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: [ExtractZipStep] starting.
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: Cleaning files in /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: Extracted zip package in /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: [OryxBuildStep] starting.
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: Skipping oryx build (remotebuild = false).
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: [PackageZipStep] starting.
9:52:54 PM kpflexfn: Linux Consumption plan has a 1.5 GB memory limit on a remote build container. To check our service limit, please visit https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: Created zip file with artifacts as /home/site/artifacts/afc58a19-91a7-4eb2-8fde-5eda946c06c1.zip.
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: [UploadPackageStep] starting.
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: Using Kudu.Legion.Core.Storage.BlobContainerStorage
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: Created blob name: released-package.zip
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: Created blob uri: https://defaultresourcegrouacdb.blob.core.windows.net/app-package-kpflexfn-5736f60/released-package.zip
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: Created Storage Credentials using storage account connection string
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: Uploaded blob successfully.
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: Uploaded package to storage blob. Deployment is partially successful from here.
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: [RemoveWorkersStep] starting.
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: RemoveAllWorkers, statusCode = NoContent
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: Reset all workers was successful.
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: [SyncTriggerStep] starting.
9:52:55 PM kpflexfn: Waiting 60 seconds for the workers to recycle with deployed content.
9:53:55 PM kpflexfn: [CleanUpStep] starting.
9:53:55 PM kpflexfn: Cleaned the source packages directory.
9:53:55 PM kpflexfn: Cleaned the result artifact directory.
9:53:55 PM kpflexfn: Finished deployment pipeline.
9:53:56 PM kpflexfn: FunctionHostSyncTrigger, statusCode = OK
9:53:56 PM kpflexfn: Performed sync triggers successfully.
9:54:03 PM kpflexfn: Started postDeployTask "npm install (functions)".

Portal:

Logs:


I have done this and is deploying fine as a normal function but adding a durable function (using the fan-out model specifically) seems to yield the BadGateway error.
